# How to get DNS server IP(s) from hostName in java

Tags: java

**Situation:** I am trying to get the DNS servers Entries/Details from each system. Now each system can have different DNS IPs.

**Ques:** How do I get/fetch DNS server IP(s) from hostname in java ?

I did this:`LinkedList<String> nameservers = (LinkedList<String>) sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration.open().nameservers();` and I am able to get the DNS details of my localsystem - but I want to get the details of other systems aswell.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You cannot read those settings from a remote machine. That would be slightly funny in terms of security.

Comment: If you're willing to use terminal commands in your code you can do it using psexec or something similar. But yeah that's usually localhost only.. unless you can read the hosts file of the remote server. that might help you too.

Comment: Why? You don't need the DNS servers themselves, or even the ability to resolve hosts to IP addresses. In most use cases Java does it automatically for you, and when you need it manually there is the `InetAdderess` class. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I am trying to get the DNS Ip addresses of those remote systems.